# Method requires being in cross-replica context, use get_replica_context().merge_call()

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras, training-data

I'm getting this runtime error in my custom loss function, inside which I have further used model.predict() to calculate a certain loss

```
RuntimeError: Method requires being in cross-replica context, use get_replica_context().merge_call()
```

Here is the code of my custom loss function:

```
#y_true passed is dummy, loading y_true from saved NumPy array to compare with

#load model
model = load_model()

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_true= np.load("../data/test/embedding_vector.npy")        
    
    y_pred_output = model.predict(y_pred)

    loss = tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity(y_pred_output, y_true)
    return loss
```

Comment: are you using a distribution strategy? see the docs for help with custom training loops: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training#training_loop

Comment: Have you found what the root of the problem was ?